# USB Virtual COM

Tags: embedded, usbserial

Looking for skeleton/source for embedded (non PC) USB Virtual COM implementation?

Comment: you need to provide a little bit more information about your hardware/software

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your processor.

For instance, ST provides a VCP example for their STM32 line. FreeRTOS also provides examples for AT91 parts.

Comment: +1 what processor is key. A USB serial port is a reference design of almost every micro with on-board USB.

Answer (score 0):

I never used LibUSB for ARV famyli, it is software USB, requires no special chip on device, but some external hardvare to be placed on PCB. I never used it but it probably will have high support from avr freks site